# Select SQL from multiple tables with identical structure

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  * 
FROM table1, 
     table2, 
     table3 
ORDER BY id ASC 
      LIMIT
```

how to do this right? I'm using MySQL and all the tables have identical structure.

Comment: What output do you expect? What did you tried to do?

Comment: You are probably looking for the UNION statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: What is your db schema?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT  * FROM table1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  * FROM table2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  * FROM table3   
) as l
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50
```

UNION will only work when you have same number of columns in each table

Comment: Have you tried it? It showing error Message : Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias 0.015 sec

Answer (score 4):

**1 -** While assuming from statement *identical structure* that all three tables have a column `id` which us used as a primary-foreign key in these tables. And you need record for a particular id from all these three.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM table1 t1, 
     table2 t2, 
     table3 t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id 
-- ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This will give you the top 10 records from all three tables related a particular `id`.

**2 -** Assuming you just to combine results from three different queries into one statement and prioritize them by `id`

```
SELECT  * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  * FROM table2
UNION
SELECT  * FROM table3
--ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

- In case you need record from the last un-comment the statement `-- ORDER BY id DESC` *assuming you have an incrementing `id` column*
- If you need more record than just change *10* in `LIMIT` to your required number.
- Please note: *The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the `UNION ALL`.*

Comment: I think he is looking for `UNION`

Comment: possible but unclear. The `query` he was trying to write, for me it seems like he wants records from three tables according to their `id`s.

Comment: @SajjadHashmi  As per your answer the query will showing only the row matching in table1.id=table2.id  and table2.id = table3.id. Means it will show the matching records only. But the question is different. So I m not agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set

```
(SELECT u.name FROM user as u where u.active=1) UNION (SELECT pu.name FROM productuser as pu WHERE pu.active=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  * 
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT  * 
FROM table3
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Preferably you would specify the columns you need rather than use * to reduce the memory required.

Comment: Can I do this "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table1` UNION SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table2` UNION SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table3` UNION SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table4` UNION SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table5`" ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. It may be time consuming depending on the size of your tables. You will also get 5 separate rows returned, not one combined sum.

Comment: You may also wish to name your column: count(id) as total